# Dynamically create javascript plugin elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-slider

I'm trying to dynamically add a [bootstrap-slider](http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/) to my webpage. However, the added slider for some reason isn't getting initialized.

The following jsfiddle demonstrates my problem: https://jsfiddle.net/hLrptave/1/

I have 2 sliders: one currently living on the page (and it works correctly) and one that's dynamically created by javascript when I click a button. The two sliders are exactly the same but the dynamically created one doesn't work (it looks like a regular text input).

The sliders are initialized by jQuery (or javascript) and both have the following code:

```
<input type="text" class="slider" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="10" data-slider-value="5">
```

So my question is how do I initialize something that doesn't exist on the page yet?

Keep in mind I have lots of these buttons on my webpage. Not sure if that affects anything or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add

```
$('.slider').slider();
```

after

```
$('#box').append(slider2);
```

I would advise you to change the classname of the new slider to slider1 beacuse when you create the new one the previous one goes back to middle if they have the same classname

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hLrptave/2/)

Comment: I've noticed I need to initialize the slider AFTER adding the created element to the DOM. Why can't I initialize it directly after I created the slider input (e.g. before adding it to the DOM)?

Answer (score 1):

Once you've added the new slider, initialize it directly:

```js
$('.slider').slider(); // Initialize pre-existing sliders
$('#button').click(function(){
  var $last = $('.slider').last();
  $last = $('<br>').insertAfter($last);
  $('<input>')
    .addClass('slider')
    .attr('type', 'text')
    .insertAfter($last)
    .slider({ // Initialize this newly created slider
      min: 0,
      max: 10,
      value: 5
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.7.1/css/bootstrap-slider.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.7.1/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="slider" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="10" data-slider-value="5">
<div id="box">
  <button id="button">Add Slider</button>
</div>
```